# Is this all lips position for creating shape keys for lips rigging?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I'm wondering how many shape keys you need to create for lip rigging. So far it seemed to me that shape keys are enough for all positions of the lips indicated in the picture. Are there any other lip poses in which to create shape keys?
[image]
P.S. - I want to get a face rig that is not inferior in quality to Rain with Blender Cloud. ( video [preview of rig](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvG956AFc4Q) )

Comment: This one is missing :-/ And will the shapekeys work with an open mouth like :D? Or the [opposite](https://depositphotos.com/141208030/stock-photo-spanish-sad-woman-serious-and.html)?

Comment: I guess it completely depends on your storyboard. Also maybe it would be better to use bones, but again it depends on several criterias

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not.  For pronouncing letters, you need many different positions.  You can find a sample chart for simplified English [here](https://www.123rf.com/photo_82114398_lips-sound-pronunciation-chart-mouth-shape-correct-position-learning-articulation-movement-of-speech.html), for example.

In addition, people don't always move their lips in a symmetric fashion.  Harrison Ford's famous grin from Indiana Jones involves one side of his mouth being higher than the other.  This sort of asymmetry helps gives each character a unique personality.

Comment: Yes, "[Contempt is what you feel when someone fails to meet your standards](https://nottrivialbook.com/emotions/contempt/)". It's the only facial expression that is one-sided.

Comment: @Blunder there are a lot of one sided facial expressions. "lop sided grin" isn't always an expression of contempt, either.  Ford used it in four or five different ways, coupled with his eye expressions to give different readings.

Comment: Sorry, I meant contempt is the only asymmetrical of the 7 basic emotions and their facial expressions (anger, contempt, disgust, fear, happiness, sadness, surprise). Of course, not every facial expression is symmetrical ;-)